# Using Coefficient to pick combinations of parameters in an expression

Tags: symbolic

I have the expression
$$
c \partial_{\chi} u = \mu u - \nu v - (u + \beta v)|A|^2 + (\partial_{\chi}^2 u - \alpha \partial_{\chi}^2 v) + \gamma u \\
c \partial_{\chi} v = \mu v + \nu u - (v - \beta u)|A|^2 + ( \alpha \partial_{\chi}^2 u + \partial_{\chi}^2 v) - \gamma v
$$
in which I make the replacement
$$
u(\chi) = u_B (\chi) + \epsilon u_R (\chi) \\
v(\chi) = v_B (\chi) + \epsilon v_R (\chi) \\
c= \epsilon c
$$
for multiple scale analysis. The parameters $\nu$, $\alpha$, and $\beta$ are of order $\epsilon << 1$. Therefore, the expression for the 1st order will contain $\epsilon$, $\alpha$, $\beta$ or $\nu$, but not terms of higher orders in $\epsilon$ or multiplications of those parameters. Can I use `Coefficient` in a way to pick out only terms that have $\epsilon$, $\alpha$, $\beta$ or $\nu$, but not higher order terms?

Comment: Please post Mathematica code, not just TeX. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple method.  First, I'll construct an expression that has lots of cross terms:

```
 expr = Sum[a[i, j, k] x^i y^j z^k, {i, 0, 4}, {j, 0, 3}, {k, 0, 2}];
```

Then I'll use `CoefficientRules` to pull out all the coefficients, `Select` to keep only those with total order of 1 or less, and then `FromCoefficientRules` to put it back together again:

```
FromCoefficientRules[
 Select[
  CoefficientRules[expr, {x, y, z}],
  Total[First[#]] <= 1 &
 ], {x, y, z}]
(* => a[0, 0, 0] + z a[0, 0, 1] + y a[0, 1, 0] + x a[1, 0, 0] *)
```

you can use a shorter list like `{x, y}` instead of `{x, y, z}` to only eliminate cross terms from a subset of variables.